# WPF Textblock Convert Issue

Tags: wpf, textblock

am usina text block in usercontrol, but am sending value to textblock from other form, when i pass some value it viewed in textblock, but i need to convert the number to text. so i used converter in textblock. but its not working

```
 <TextBlock Height="21" Name="txtStatus" Width="65" Background="Bisque" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=hM1,Converter={StaticResource TextConvert},Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

converter class

```
class TextConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                return value = "Good";

            }
            if (value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                return value = "NIL";

            }

       }
        return value = "";
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (string)value;
    }

}
```

is it right? whats wrong in it??

Comment: yes, I would like to know the output as well....it looks right.

Comment: yes am getting number in textblock,the values are 0 and 1, if 0 will bind some text as same for 1 some text, am getting the numebr value in textblock, but converter is not working to replace the number for text

Answer (score 4):

ok I think I know what the problem is - let see if I can define it for you :)

in your xaml file where you want to use TextConvert, define Resource for it (unless you are doing it already, then I haven't a clue why its not working)

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Shared:TextConvert x:Key="TextConvertKey" />
    </Grid.Resources>
```

shared being the xmlns ofcourse.

Then in the textbox use it like:

```
Text="{Binding Path=hM1,Converter={StaticResource TextConvertKey},Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

EDIT:

If you set a breakpoint in the converter class, does the debugger go in there?????

EDIT 2:

am using like this voodoo

local:HealthTextConvert x:Key="TextConvert"

This is absolutely wrong. How can you Call it HealthTextConvert when the converter name is TextConvert???

it should be

```
local:TextConvert x:Key="whateverKeyNameYouWant"
```

and

in the textbox is should be

```
Text="{Binding Path=hM1,Converter={StaticResource whateverKeyNameYouWant},Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: i have already added it to my grid resources..

but its stil convert class is not working

Comment: let me see what hM1 looks like?

Comment: hM1 is a variable,it may be 0 or 1

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the converter class, does the debugger go in there?????

Comment: no, i ichecked that too, its does not going to that break point.

Comment: I would check the output window in VS to see what kind of errors you are getting...The are exceptions being thrown by SL

Comment: none error am getting, evrythng works well with out any exception. i just added converter class to the textblock,but the output remain same, only the converter class is not working, i can get the output without conversion and without exception

Comment: are you using the "{StaticResource TextConvertKey}"? like I said in my solution. You can't use the converter name here (i.e. TextConvert)

Comment: am using like this voodoo <UserControl.Resources> <local:HealthTextConvert x:Key="TextConvert"/> </UserControl.Resources>

Comment: Dont forget to specify the local namespace in the top of your xaml ;)

Comment: no i did correctly, but still not convert not working vodoo.. don know why

Comment: what is the name of the file in which Converter resides in and namespace? what is your xmlns for local???

Answer (score 1):

I can see immediately a problem with your converter definition.

```
class TextConvert : IValueConverter
{
    ...
```

Should be declared public to be able to use it as a resource.

```
public class TextConvert : IValueConverter
{
    ...
```

Also, its not a good thing to be doing this...

```
return value = "Good";

...

return value = "NIL";
```

It should just be (even though it will not matter if you leave it, just bad programming =P):

```
return "Good";

...

return "Nill";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `Path` in the below line

```
Text="{Binding **Path**=hM1,Converter={StaticResource TextConvert},Mode=OneWay}".
```

Sometimes it works without `Path` :).

Also look into the output window(Alt+Cntl+O)...to see where the issue is.

Comment: Deep ..did u get the answer ?

Comment: Namespace shud be like this - xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary2.ViewModel" And Class in that namespace shud be used as below - <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Datas" ObjectType="{x:Type ViewModel:UserControlViewModel}"></ObjectDataProvider>

Comment: using ObjectDataProvider...u can have the instance of a class as a static resource

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake from my part :(

Please look at the following link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx